# jquery accordion html code

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

i have this js fiddle, but i have no idea how to fully write it in an html document so that it'll show up like it's supposed to. there's the html aspect, the javascript aspect, the jquery aspect, and the css part. it just confuses the heck out of me. can anyone help?

http://jsfiddle.net/DkHyd/

```
<h1>Toggle Panels</h1>
<div id="notaccordion">
  <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris  ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus  nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a  nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur  malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula.  Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet,  mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.  Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac,  risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede.  Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed  commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo  purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item  three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique  senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante  ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;  Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer  dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per  conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
     </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting everything together...  You will get this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        $.fn.togglepanels = function(){
          return this.each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("ui-accordion ui-accordion-icons ui-widget ui-helper-reset")
          .find("h3")
            .addClass("ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom")
            .hover(function() { $(this).toggleClass("ui-state-hover"); })
            .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>')
            .click(function() {
              $(this)
                .toggleClass("ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-state-default ui-corner-bottom")
                .find("> .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-triangle-1-e ui-icon-triangle-1-s").end()
                .next().slideToggle();
              return false;
            })
            .next()
              .addClass("ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom")
              .hide();
          });
        };

        $("#notaccordion").togglepanels();
    });
    </script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Toggle Panels</h1>
    <div id="notaccordion">
      <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Mauris mauris  ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
        ut neque. Vivamus  nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
        amet, nunc. Nam a  nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
        odio. Curabitur  malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
      </div>
      <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula.  Vestibulum sit amet
        purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet,  mauris turpis porttitor
        velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo.  Vivamus non quam. In
        suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
      </div>
      <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac,  risus. Quisque lobortis.
        Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede.  Phasellus ac libero
        ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed  commodo, magna quis
        lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo  purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>List item one</li>
          <li>List item two</li>
          <li>List item  three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
      <div>
        <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique  senectus et netus
        et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante  ipsum primis in
        faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;  Aenean lacinia
        mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
        Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer  dignissim consequat lectus.
        Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per  conubia nostra, per
        inceptos himenaeos.
         </p>
      </div>
    </div>                                                                                                                      
</body>
</html>
```

Just paste the above code into a notepad and save it as index.html .. you are pretty much ready.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

There id no need to worry about the jQuery code you have.

Here accordion is very simplified using [**jQuery UI Accordion**](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

```
$('#notaccordion').accordion();  //This is enough to play with jQuery accordion
```

Reference you should add:

**jQuery UI CSS:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

**jQuery.js:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
```

**jQueryUI.js:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"/>
```

Go through this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DkHyd/1550/)

Offline should look like

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"/>
<script>
$('#notaccordion').accordion();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Place your HTML Code-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you just put your JS into a .js file and save it in your project. After that, you just include it in your .html file. Assuming that your .js file is in /js folder in the root of your project, you would include it like this between  and :

```
<script src="./js/file.js"></script>
```

After this, you should be fine working with it. Including css is straight forward, too. Just do it like this, assuming your .css file is in the /css folder in the root of your project:

```
<link href="./css/file.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Hope I could help.